# SQL server: copy database from LINUX version to Win version

Tags: sql-server, linux, ssms

I am using Red Hat Linux version of MS sql server 2019 dev edition on a QNAP NAS.

As I can backup the data on the NAS just by creating a snapshot of the whole docker file but not the SQL-database itself (as I do not know howto) I wanted to move from LINUX back to SQL-Server on Windows.

I tried to copy the database using the task in SSMS but received an error without further description
TITEL: Assistent zum Kopieren von Datenbanken

No description found

Both versions are Server 2019 but of course one is running on Linux the other on Windows.
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8) (KB4577194) - 15.0.4073.23 (X64)... Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa))

versus

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)...Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 19042: )

I tried by lowering the compatibility level to Server 2016 but same error.

How can I copy (export) the datebase from Linux??

Comment: What do you mean by you "tried to copy the database using SSMS"? You don't copy a database. Often you would create a backup and then restore it on the target host.

Comment: I must admit, as well, installing Enterprise on a Windows 10 host seems odd; I would expect that to be running on a server, not a PC.

Comment: In SSMS there is a task called Copy database and thats why I copy it. Further, on Linux it is running in a docker and I cannot even change a backup destination. The only idea I've got is to use SSNS for copying the db into another server.

Comment: I've personally never used the "Copy Database" feature, as I would much rather use a backup. Even with containers, you can still create a backup and copy it across. You'll likely need to mount a directory on the host system to the docker and possibly set the permissions for the `mssql` user/group first though.

Comment: I suppose that I did something wrong in creating the docker on NAS, maybe didn't define a shared folder or something like this. I can't see the data base in folder var/opt/msssql/data. It seems to be empty on filestation, but SSMS points to this folder.
Also when making backup, the location points to this folder but in Filestation nothing is in this folder.

Comment: `/var/opt/mssql` is a directory in the container, not the container's host.

Comment: What does this mean?
why does the database point to var/opt/msssql/data? Isn't this the location of the db?
But how can I get the data out of this container??

Comment: Like I said, I would perform a back up, and put the file in a directory that is a mount point to a directory located on the container's host. Then you can copy that file from one host to the new host and restore.

Comment: Well, I was somehow confused by the task "Databse copy". 
I tried  "database export" and could easyly export it from docker on Linux NAS to SQL Server on Windows.
A backup on the NAS and a restore on the Windwos couldn't be done to above problems. It took me long time right now for a problem of only 5 minutes ot solve if I would have done it the easy way.  Now I could setup the container on the NAS for new with a shared folder as the data location as I think this is the main problem for not getting it correct the first time.